# How can we specify a custom lambda sequence to glmnet

Tags: r, parameters, glmnet, lasso-regression, hyperparameters

I am new to the `glmnet` package in `R`, and wanted to specify a `lambda` function based on the suggestion in a published research paper to the `glmnet.cv` function. The documentation suggests that we can supply a decreasing sequence of `lambdas` as a parameter.  However, in the documentation there are no examples of how to do this.

It would be very grateful if someone can suggest how to go about doing this.  Do I pass a vector of 100 odd values (default value for `nlambda`) to the function?  What restrictions should be there for the min and max value of this vector, if any?   Also, are their things to keep in mind regarding `nvars`, `nobs` etc. while specifying the vector?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The question is about how to properly code a procedure in `R` so it seems appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 7):

You can define a grid like this :

```
    grid=10^seq(10,-2,length=100) ##get lambda sequence
    ridge_mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0,lambda=grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy though it's not well explained in the original documentation ;)

In the following I've used cox family but you can change it based on your need

```
my_cvglmnet_fit <- cv.glmnet(x=regression_data, y=glmnet_response, family="cox", maxit = 100000)
```

Then you can plot the fitted object created by the cv.glmnet and in the plot you can easily see where the lambda is minimum. one of those dotted vertical lines is the minimum lambda and the other one is the 1se.

```
plot(my_cvglmnet_fit)
```

the following lines helps you see the non zero coefficients and their corresponding values:

```
coef(my_cvglmnet_fit, s = "lambda.min")[which(coef(my_cvglmnet_fit, s = "lambda.min") != 0)]  # the non zero coefficients
colnames(regression_data)[which(coef(my_cvglmnet_fit, s = "lambda.min") != 0)]  # The features that are selected
```

here are some links that may help:
http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html
http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/05/hastie-glmnet.html